# Python 2.6 from human date to seconds

Tags: python, date, seconds

Since there is no `total_seconds()` for python 2.6, I use formula  `(dt.microseconds + (dt.seconds + dt.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6` to find total seconds for a number of days that comes from: `dt.strptime("date_from_user","%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") - datetime(1970, 1, 1)`.
I don't understand why for any `date_from_user`(e.g. "25.07.2015 00:00:00"), I've got back a number of seconds corresponding to the input date but with 2 hours added. In this example "25.07.2015 02:00:00".

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 UTC +2! Is that the reason?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 How should I handle utc timezone?

Comment: Using your code (correcting the `'H%'` to `'%H'`, etc.), your manual calculation is producing the same number as the `total_seconds` method does in my 2.7 interpreter, and I'm UTC-8. Feeding that value of seconds into `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp` produces the original date (midnight 7/25/2015).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks, but I had some problems with datetime object returned from utcfromtimestamp. I solved using module time and the way suggested in this conversion table: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html?#module-time

Comment: It sounds like you should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To simply convert a human date into seconds from epoch(for unix systems), I used 'Time' module and followed this recommended way from the Python docs, as showed in the table:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html

This works for Python 2.6